# How to download binary files from a public github repository through the command line?

Tags: github

I'm trying to work through this docker-zfs plug in: https://github.com/TrilliumIT/docker-zfs-plugin. I'm stuck at this line: Download the latest binary from github releases and place in /usr/local/bin/ .

How does one do such a thing? I've done through the whole page, and I don't see any mention of binary files/a link for a release. I've looked at other pages to download from Github repositories, but I don't have any authentication so they didn't seem applicable. I looked at this and tried to make it work, https://geraldonit.com/2019/01/15/how-to-download-the-latest-github-repo-release-via-command-line/ , but something about the link formatting didn't seem to work. This must be really obvious but I don't see what I am missing.

This is what I tried:
LOCATION=$(curl -s https://github.com/TrilliumIT/docker-zfs-plugin/releases/latest 
| grep "tag_name" 
| awk '{print "https://github.com/TrilliumIT/docker-zfs-plugin/releases/latest" substr($2, 2, length($2)-3) ".zip"}') 
; curl -L -o . /usr/local/bin/

(But I'm not sure this is what I need, and the link doesn't exist either. There must be a better way of doing this?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok so I actually figured this out, it was simpler than I was doing:

```
wget https://github.com/TrilliumIT/docker-zfs-plugin/releases/download/v1.0.5/docker-zfs-plugin
sudo mv docker-zfs-plugin /usr/local/bin/
```